# vim autoload folder permission denied?

Tags: vim, autoload

I'm trying to edit files in my .vim/autoload folder but somehow I don't have permission. sudo doesn't work. I've never had this issue before. The only change is that I've upgraded to a new macbook but all directories are the same.

Comment: Do you have permission to use `sudo`? How are you using `sudo`? What error do you get that it "doesn't work"?

Comment: @jeremysprofile When i try to cd into the autoload folder i get `cd: permission denied: autoload` sudo cd doesn't do anything

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work

Comment: Possible repost of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23024/18609

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.vim` show you?

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [the repost in Vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/23024/18609).

Problem was directory was created with `sudo`.

Solved with:

```
$ sudo chown -Rh gabe:staff ~/.vim
$ chmod -R a+rX,u+w,go-w ~/.vim
```